# What is causing: "ERROR -- : app error: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String (TypeError)" in my rack app?

Tags: ruby, rack, unicorn

I'm running a simple rack based app for image processing on the fly. In my log I see tons of those. Where might this originate from and how do I fix it?

```
[2015-10-07T16:16:20.299285 #18586] ERROR -- : app error: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String (TypeError)
E, [2015-10-07T16:16:20.299510 #18586] ERROR -- : /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@au-images/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/reloader.rb:87:in `initialize'
E, [2015-10-07T16:16:20.299560 #18586] ERROR -- : /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@au-images/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/reloader.rb:87:in `new'
E, [2015-10-07T16:16:20.299603 #18586] ERROR -- : /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@au-images/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/reloader.rb:87:in `figure_path'
E, [2015-10-07T16:16:20.299644 #18586] ERROR -- : /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@au-images/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/reloader.rb:73:in `block in rotation'
E, [2015-10-07T16:16:20.299683 #18586] ERROR -- : /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@au-images/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/reloader.rb:70:in `map'
E, [2015-10-07T16:16:20.299723 #18586] ERROR -- : /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@au-images/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/reloader.rb:70:in `rotation'
E, [2015-10-07T16:16:20.299762 #18586] ERROR -- : /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@au-images/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/reloader.rb:48:in `reload!'
E, [2015-10-07T16:16:20.299800 #18586] ERROR -- : /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@au-images/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/reloader.rb:36:in `block in call'
E, [2015-10-07T16:16:20.299840 #18586] ERROR -- : <internal:prelude>:12:in `block in exclusive'
E, [2015-10-07T16:16:20.299878 #18586] ERROR -- : <internal:prelude>:11:in `synchronize'
E, [2015-10-07T16:16:20.299916 #18586] ERROR -- : <internal:prelude>:11:in `exclusive'
E, [2015-10-07T16:16:20.299953 #18586] ERROR -- : /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@au-images/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/reloader.rb:36:in `call'
E, [2015-10-07T16:16:20.299993 #18586] ERROR -- : /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@au-images/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:580:in `process_client'
E, [2015-10-07T16:16:20.300052 #18586] ERROR -- : /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@au-images/gems/unicorn-worker-killer-0.4.3/lib/unicorn/worker_killer.rb:52:in `process_client'
E, [2015-10-07T16:16:20.300095 #18586] ERROR -- : /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@au-images/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:674:in `worker_loop'
E, [2015-10-07T16:16:20.300134 #18586] ERROR -- : /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@au-images/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:529:in `spawn_missing_workers'
E, [2015-10-07T16:16:20.300173 #18586] ERROR -- : /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@au-images/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:540:in `maintain_worker_count'
E, [2015-10-07T16:16:20.300212 #18586] ERROR -- : /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@au-images/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:294:in `join'
E, [2015-10-07T16:16:20.300251 #18586] ERROR -- : /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@au-images/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `<top (required)>'
E, [2015-10-07T16:16:20.300289 #18586] ERROR -- : /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@au-images/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `load'
E, [2015-10-07T16:16:20.300327 #18586] ERROR -- : /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@au-images/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `<main>'
E, [2015-10-07T16:16:20.300365 #18586] ERROR -- : /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@au-images/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
E, [2015-10-07T16:16:20.300403 #18586] ERROR -- : /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@au-images/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to do mathematical calculation on a Text(string) if it's a number but under a string type add `to_i` then it won't throw this error.

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly the answer I was looking for, maybe I didn't formulate my question well enough :-)